# How to eager load a polymorphic model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism, eager-loading

I'm trying to optimize some of our queries. One particular challenge was trying to eager load a polymorphic model. In this case, `UserView` is polymorphic and has the following columns:

```
user_id, user_viewable_id, user_viewable_type
```

When I try to run this query.

```
@user_views = UserView.select('user_views.* AS user_views, songs.* AS songs, users.* AS users')
  .joins('INNER JOIN users AS users ON user_views.user_id = users.id')
  .joins('INNER JOIN songs AS songs ON user_views.user_viewable_id = songs.id')
  .where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').order('user_views.id DESC').limit(5)
```

It doesn't seem to eager load the query. I am using a gem called [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler), which indicates that it is actually running n+1 queries, instead of just one.

The following AR query returns this SQL:

```
SELECT user_views.* AS user_views, songs.* AS songs, users.* AS users FROM "user_views" INNER JOIN users AS users ON user_views.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN songs AS songs ON user_views.user_viewable_id = songs.id WHERE "user_views"."user_viewable_type" = 'Song' ORDER BY user_views.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Which returns the records all in one query. Strange why this is not working as expected in AR.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16124295/936494) is a good discussion on this stuff. Hope it helps gain better insights on this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rails documentation about eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations) says `includes` works with polymorphic associations. So you should just write:

```
@user_views = UserView.includes(:user_viewable).
  where(:user_viewable_type => 'Song').order('id DESC').limit(5)
```