# eager load ActiveRecord polymorphic associations that are 'has_one'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My problem is pretty much the same as the answer throughly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123492/eager-load-polymorphic), except I need to eager load records that are `has_one` from the polymorphic table.

My models are as follows:

```
class VisionSource 
  has_one :entity_map, as: :entity_mappable
end

class EntityMap 
  belongs_to :entity_mappable, polymorphic: true
end
```

How can I then write something verbatim like this `EntityMap.includes(:entity_mappable)`?

Comment: perhaps you can find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909257/how-to-eager-load-a-polymorphic-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just work for you out of the box. I suspect it looks like it's not firing because you're not asking for something from the EntityMappable

Try this:

`EntityMap.includes(:entity_mappable).map(&:entity_mappable).map(&:class).map(&:name).uniq`

I tried this with a couple of classes that use EntityMappable and the above gives this SQL output in rails console:

`EntityMap Load (0.9ms)  SELECT`entity_maps`.* FROM`entity_maps`ORDER BY`entity_maps`.`position`ASC
  CameraShot Load (0.4ms)  SELECT`vision_sources`.* FROM`vision_sources`WHERE`vision_sources`.`type`IN ('CameraShot') AND`vision_sources`.`id`IN (89, 87, 88, 90, 85, 86) ORDER BY`vision_sources`.`position`ASC
  Sound Load (0.3ms)  SELECT`sounds`.* FROM`sounds`WHERE`sounds`.`id` = 1

Note that the CameraShot model is a subclass of VisionSource which uses STI (and thus the type field to define itself), while the Sound model effectively looks like this:

```
class Sound
  has_one :entity_map, as: :entity_mappable
end
```